# Calculation of the second variation of the functional $I(y)=\int_{-1}^1 [x^2(y')^2+x(y')^3]\,dx$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

[image]

**My question:**

I don't understand the last equation about second variation. According to definition, shouldn't it be $\int_{-1}^1 [2x^2+6xy'] (\eta)^2$?

Can anyone help me with this? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing $y$ with $y+\eta$ yields 
$$
\int_{-1}^1 [x^2(y'+\eta')^2+x(y'+\eta')^3]\,dx
$$
where the quadratic term is 
$$
\frac12 \delta^2I_y (\eta)=\int_{-1}^1 [x^2 (\eta')^2+3xy'(\eta')^2]\,dx
$$
The author considers second variation at $y=0$, where it takes the form 
$$
\frac12  \delta^2I_0 (\eta)=\int_{-1}^1 x^2 (\eta')^2\,dx
$$